# Java concurrency & cyclic task execution

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, timer, scheduled-tasks

I have a task that consists of 20 different steps:

```
public class MyTask implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Step #1. Fetch data
        Data data = fetchData();

        // Step #2. Do something with data
        SomeResult result = dataProcessor.process(data);

        // ...

        // Step #19. Generate report
        Report report = reportFactory.newReport(result);

        // Step #20. Clean up
        cleanUp();
    }
}
```

I want to:

- Start running the task at some arbirtrary time (application startup) we'll call `STARTING_POINT`.
- Run the task over and over again (`Timer`? `ScheduledExecutorService`?) every minute, on the minute, from `STARTING_POINT`.
- If the task is still running (say, it's at Step #17) when the 1 minute cycle is up, then interrupt the task and prevent it from continuing to execute, and then (again because we're statrting a new cycle every minute), start over on a new cycle (hence call `run()` again from the beginning).
- Else, if the task finishes before the 1 minute cycle is up, then reset `STARTING_POINT` to the current time (`System.currentTimeInMillis()`?) and start cycling every minute again, but from the new `STARTING_POINT`.
- Once these 1 minute cycles start, they don't stop unless interrupted by an external "Control" thread that might be called from, say, a `ShutdownHook` or something similar.

For example, let's say the app starts up, and `STARTING_POINT` is 2/4/2014 11:15:36 EST. Let's say the 1st cycle takes *exactly* 1 minute to finish executing all 20 steps inside `run()`. It would then execute between 11:15:36 and 11:16:36, and then the 2nd cycle would start over again and call `run()`. Let's say this cycle was slow and by the time we get to 11:17:36 it's only on Step #11. It would shut down and stop executing, and then a 3rd cycle would start over again and call `run()`. If this cycle was fast and was all done with `run()` by 11:17:53, then `STARTING_POINT` would become 2/4/2014 11:17:53, and a 4th cycle would start executing and call `run()` again. Etc.

I have absolutely no idea where to even begin digging in with this. Any ideas?  I'm open to the use of anything that ships with the JDK, and any open source libraries besides Apache Camel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like [Spring Batch](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/) would be a good one to consider. I would recommend it.

You can schedule the jobs with spring integrated quartz scheduler.
A job will be split into multiple steps (and parallelism can also be achieved).
Jobs could be re-started and best of all everything is right there that you have minimal work.

Most of the stuff goes in wiring it properly. I provided a bean configuration as example.

```
    <bean id="threadPoolExecutor"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="20" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="25" />
    <property name="queueCapacity" value="500" />
</bean>
<bean id="jobLauncher"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
    <property name="taskExecutor" ref="asyncTaskExecutor" />
</bean>

<batch:job id="batchjob" job-repository="jobRepository">
    <batch:step id="step1" next="step2">
        <batch:tasklet ref="start" />
    </batch:step>
    <batch:step id="step2" next="step3.master">
        <batch:tasklet ref="fetchData" />
    </batch:step>
    <batch:step id="step3.master">
        <batch:partition step="step3.slave"
            partitioner="processingPartitioner">
            <batch:handler grid-size="20" task-executor="threadPoolExecutor" />
        </batch:partition>
    </batch:step>
    <batch:listeners>
        <batch:listener ref="MyListener" />
    </batch:listeners>
</batch:job>

<batch:step id="step3.slave">
    <batch:tasklet ref="processFile" />
</batch:step>

<bean id="myLauncher" class="com.<>.batch.MyLauncher">
    <property name="job" ref="batchJob" />
    <property name="jobLauncher" ref="jobLauncher" />
</bean>

<task:scheduled-tasks>
    <task:scheduled ref="myLauncher" method="launch"
        cron="0 0 0 0 0 1" />
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

Each step could be defined and should implement Tasklet. There are examples provided by spring itself.

Comment: Thanks @aNish (+1) - can you give a code or pseudo-code example of how this might play out?

Answer (score 0):

cancel() would cancel the current thread. can you check for time after each of your 20 methods and call cancel.

```
time2.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        @Override
        public void run() {
          if (System.currentTimeMillis() - t0 ) {
              cancel();
          } else {
              sendSamples();
          }
        }
```